# Query sql pivot on date transformation

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called LAB and it has these important field:

**DATA, CODE, STRUTT.** 
DATA contains dates, code string and strutt integer as well

What I need is to query this table and get back something like:

```
-----------------------
| DAYS | YEAR | YEAR2 |
-----------------------
|    |     STRUTT     |
-----------------------
|    |        |       |
```

They suggest me to use pivot. But I don't know how to group years. 
My first try was:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT STRUTT, CODe, DATA
  FROM LAB
  WHERE DATA  >= DATE '2016-05-01' AND DATA <= DATE '2016-05-31'
)
PIVOT 
(
  count(DISTINCT CODE)
  FOR STRUTT IN (21,22,23,24,25,26)
)
```

This is a start for my use of Pivot. But then i tried to change the for statement and put:

```
FOR DATA IN ('2016-05-01','2016-05-21')
```

but this gave me errors. Some ideas for solve the entire problem? Or at least to solve the last one of dates? ***SOLVED BUT NOT NEEDED AT THE END TO SOLVE THE PROBLEM***

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Oracle.  I might suggest trying:

```
FOR DATA IN (DATE '2016-05-01', DATE '2016-05-21')
```

Otherwise, the string values are interpreted as strings, not dates.

Comment: thank you for the syntax. Yes, I'm using Oracle. I tried multiple syntaxes but got nothing. I searched on google and nothing as well for this particular case.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by having a look somewhere... I still don't know which version of Oracle I'm using. By the way this work for me:

```
select strutt
         , to_char(data,'dd-MON') AS dayMonth
         , count(DISTINCT (case extract(year from data) when 2015 then code end)) numutenze_2015
         , count(DISTINCT (case extract(year from data) when 2016 then code end)) numutenze_2016
from lab
where data >= DATE '2015-01-01' and data <= DATE '2016-06-08'
group by strutt, to_char(data,'dd-MON')
order by strutt, to_char(data,'dd-MON') asc
```

The only problem I have, I don't know how to order the Dates... it start from April, then August... ecc